# Background hover showing in CSS

Tags: css

There's a background hover in the bootstrap 'More' dropdown in the left nav [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/links.html) which I'm trying to get rid of, I can't see where the background colour is coming from and I removed all background hovers.

Anyone know how I can locate the CSS affecting it?

Comment: Use 'Inspect element' in your browsers Developer Tools.

Comment: Inspect element / firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, this answer is dedicated to the bug in the dropdown on the right side.

Is it this piece of code that is bugging you:

Structure.css / line 596:

```
#top-nav .dropdown-menu li:hover, #top-nav .dropdown-menu a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover
{
    background-color: #464358 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I found that one with the Firebug extension for Firefox. Install, rightclick on the item, "analyze with Firebug".

Answer (score 1):

Today browsers come with built-in element inspection tools, but Firefox has the popular Firebug plugin as well. You should have the option to artificially set `:hover` on an element you are inspecting.

Anyway, you don't need to know where the rule is to override it. Just set `background-color: auto !important` on the selector, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
#top-nav .dropdown-menu li:hover, #top-nav .dropdown-menu a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
background-color: #464358 !important;}
```

Remove this lines

Comment: That has nothing to do with the background color.

Comment: I misunderstood you. Edit my answer. File - structure.css 596

Comment: The OP may not want to modify the source of the framework. Everything can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
     background: #fff !important;
     cursor: default;
   }
```

Or this if you want to achieve the same parent background color:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
   background: transparent !important;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: What if the background has to be something else than white, but as defined by the parent element?

Comment: Just put background: transparent;

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug for it `#left-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover` 
CSS line 1353